# Routing in asp.net mvc with multiple optional parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am developing a asp.net mvc 4 application where I need a custom route which will handle multiple parameters like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default",                                              
   "FilteredResults/Filter1-{1stParam}/Filter2-{2ndParam}/..../Filter-N{nthParam}",                           // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }   defaults
    );
```

I want to be able to pass only a subset of the parameters to the route(depending if some filters are selected or not)

For example if I have only the second Filter selected, I want to reference it this way:

```
<a href="/FilteredResults/Filter2-1000">
```

Is this possible to do this in a single route without creating a lot of routes for each combination of filters?

Comment: Why don't you just use query string params? /FilteredResults?filter2=1000&filter3=400 etc. That's what they are for. It seems you are trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @rism That is exactly the point, instead of `/FilteredResults?filter2=1000&filter3=400` I want to have `/FilteredResults/filter2=1000/filter3=400`

Comment: Why? What does that give you but an url with / instead of &?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with following example

On RouteConfig :

```
routes.MapRoute("Name", "tag/{*tags}", new { controller = ..., action = ... });
```

On Controller :

```
ActionResult MyAction(string tags) {
    foreach(string tag in tags.Split("/")) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I will accept this as an answer althought I found this solution on another stackoverflow post before. I thought that there would be a better solution, but in this case this seems to be the only option.

Comment: This is documented [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#Anchor_5).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [custom RouteBase](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=970) implementation that could handle this detail.

```
public class FilteredRoute : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        RouteData result = null;
        var path = httpContext.Request.Path;
        // Path always starts with a "/", so ignore it.
        var segments = path.Substring(1).Split('/');

        if (segments.Any() && segments[0].Equals("FilteredResults", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var result = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());

            result.Values["controller"] = "Filter";
            result.Values["action"] = "ProcessFilters";

            // Add filters to route data (skip the first segment)
            var filters = segments.Skip(1).ToArray();

            foreach (var filter in filters)
            {
                string key = ParseRouteKey(filter);
                var value = ParseRouteValue(filter);

                result.Values[key] = value;
            }
        }

        // Make sure to return null if this route does not match
        return result;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        VirtualPathData result = null;

        // Process outgoing route here (to rebuild the URL from @Html.ActionLink)

        return result;
    }
}
```

Note that if you do it this way, it won't matter what order the filters are supplied in as long as the URL starts with `/FilteredResults/`.

Then you just add it to your route configuration like this.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // Add the filtered route
    routes.Add("Filtered", new FilteredRoute());

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```